# Environment variables for CGI in Tomcat

Tags: perl, tomcat

I've set up CGI in Tomcat and it runs fine for one of my test scripts. Now I am trying a more sophisticated script which uses DBD/Oracle.pm and it's throwing me the following errors when I inspect the catalina.log:

StandardContext[/TestApp]cgi: runCGI (stderr):Can't locate Oracle.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ....)

When I inspect what's inside of @INC I do notice that it's missing the path which the Oracle.pm resides in. However, when I do perl -V on command, I see
@INC:
/usr/local/oracle/oraperllib/
...

which is the missing path where Oracle.pm resides in.

Is Tomcat using a different version of perl? If so, how do I configure it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running Tomcat under same user as you use command line?

Comment: Inspect `$^X` or `$Config{perlpath}` to see where the `perl` interpreter is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run Perl from the command line, you are probably picking up the non-standard path for Oracle.pm from some place like your `.bashrc` file.

When the web server runs the CGI script, it may not be picking up the same environment variables. Either move "Oracle.pm" into a standard path, or explicitly "use" the path in your CGI script:

```
use lib '/usr/local/oracle/oraperllib/';
```

Comment: I think this is what's happening, I do have the path set in .cshrc. I'd like to avoid making code changes to the script as it is deployed at multiple locations. When you said standard path, can you be more specific?

Comment: Running under Tomcat you could print out your `@INC`  to see your standard path.

Comment: I did, and they differ if I were to run the script on command line vs. opening in browser. Also, I used @mob's suggestion and I did see that browser uses /usr/bin/perl whereas command line uses /home/mydev/perl-5.8.2/bin/perl.

@ INC from browser shows missing Oracle path & command line has Oracle path. My question is, how should I set up Tomcat to include the path. I also checked /proc/<pid/environ for the tomcat instance, it did pick up the ORACLE_HOME variable...

Comment: I'm not a Tomcat user, but I get a [lot of hits](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=setting+environment+variables+in+tomcat+server) when I search for how to set environment variables in Tomcat. The variable you need to set is `PERL5LIB`. It should point the directory containing Oracle.pm. If Oracle was installed only for the *other* Perl on your system, then you may need to make sure Oracle.pm is installed for the Perl that Tomcat is talking to.

Comment: PERL5LIB didn't work for me. I went back to the last resort as Mark suggested...changing the source, I added use lib in the source and that worked.

Thank you for everyone's suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the hint from Mark about PERL5LIB is what I needed.  But there's a crucial step needed:

set **passShellEnvironment** to true in your web.xml, that is within your cgi servlet configuration:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>passShellEnvironment</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

See the tomcat documentation on this: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cgi-howto.html#Configuration. By default this option is set to false and your environment variables will not be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Same problems with Python configuration and Tomcat install into a Mac...

- Unix system are case sensitive warning to the name exec program

  ```
   <init-param>
        <param-name>executable</param-name>
        <param-value>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>passShellEnvironment</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
      </init-param>
  ```

  equal result to

  ```
      <init-param>
        <param-name>executable</param-name>
        <param-value>Python</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>passShellEnvironment</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
  ```

but the 2nd are far more efficient for avoiding installation of new python version matter

There are no error but no exécution of script just a windows for save or open the script if the script have some error.
and works if no error 
using  #!/usr/bin/env python3.6 in the first line of the script.

So be sure to have the same thing with perl.